# Resolving multiple promises at once that have dependencies on each other

Tags: ember.js

I am using [ember-async button](https://github.com/DockYard/ember-async-button) which will show a spinner until the actions promise resolves.

```
{{async-button action=(action "save" model) default="Save" pending="Saving..."}}
```

In my case I can't start the child promises until the parent promise has resolved.

This does not work, the spinner will stop as soon as the parent promise resolves.

```
actions: {
  save(model) {
    cont promise = model.save();

    promise.then(() => {
      const promises = [];
      model.get('subModels').forEach((subModel) => {
        promises.pushObject(subModel.save());
      });

      return Ember.RSVP.all(promises);
    });

    return promise;
  }
}
```

How do I keep a long running promise running until all dependent promises have finished, taking into account that some of the promises are dependent on others completing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I keep a long running promise running until all dependent promises have finished?

The initial promise resolves when it resolves (when the top-level save finishes), and you can't "keep it running". You need to return the promise for saving all the submodels.

```
return promise.then(() => {
  const promises = [];
  model.get('subModels').forEach((subModel) => {
    promises.pushObject(subModel.save());
  });
  return Ember.RSVP.all(promises);
}
```

or more simply, using `map`:

```
return promise.then(() => 
  Ember.RSVP.all(model.get('subModels').map(subModel => subModel.save()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is simple that you `return promise` instead of returning the result of `promise.then(...)`.

```
actions: {
  save(model) {
    cont promise = model.save();

    return promise.then(() => {
      const promises = [];
      model.get('subModels').forEach((subModel) => {
        promises.pushObject(subModel.save());
      });

      return Ember.RSVP.all(promises);
    });
  }
}
```